# Is this alternate proof to baby rudin 2.34 correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

I am self studying Rudin and was wondering if this works as an alternate proof to what is given in the book for Theorem 2.34. After having written it out explicitly I can see why the books version would be preferable for its terseness but nonetheless wondered if there was anything wrong with this approach as it was what came more intuitively to me.

> **2.34 Theorem** *Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed*

Let $K$ be a compact subset of a metric space $X$. By contradiction, assume that $K$ is not closed and there exists some limit point $p\notin K$.

Define a set $$G_p(r) = \{x \in X : d(p, x) > r \}$$ where $d(p,x)$ here is the distance function of the metric and $r$ is positive. This $G_p(r)$ is open as all points $q \in G_p(r)$ have some neighbourhood with radius less than $d(p,q) - r$ that are completely contained within $G_{p}(r)$.

Take $$ G = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}G_{p}(\frac{1}{i}) = X \setminus \{p\}$$

This $G$ is an open cover of $K$. Furthermore, this open cover has no finite subcover as any finite union $G' = G_{p}(\frac{1}{\alpha_1})\cup \dots \cup G_{p}(\frac{1}{\alpha_n})$ will have some minimum $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ where taking the neighborhood $N = \{x \in X : d(p, x) < \frac{1}{\alpha} \}$ about $p$ will not intersect with $G'$ and must contain some $q \neq p$ in $K$ (because $p$ was a limit point of $K$).

Because we have found some open cover with no finit subcover we have shown the $K$ is not a compact set and established our contradiction.

Comment: This is correct, but (in my humble opinion), this is far more complicated than the classical (direct, without contradiction argument) proof !